# UPLOAD statement with "dynamic" table and column names? (ORACLE/JDE)

Tags: sql, c, oracle, jde

I know that it is possible to do with **SELECT statements** (*in JDEdwards we have a business function [C language] that can do this for SELECT statements*), but I need to make a new function that can make a "dynamic upload".

In this case, **I will not have the name of the table nor the columns**, they will come from a external aplication, but I'm not figuring it out how to do it.

I think that I may have some problems with the type of the columns. Maybe with the fields too, seeing that I should pass all the fields in C code - other functions that do updates in tables have all fields in the main code, never coming from a external aplication.

Is this possible? Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, third-party system defines what (tables, data formats, data itself) to update in JDE? In this case why would you need a middleman, can you just update data in JDE from a third-party system? Are you trying to create some kind of integration platform for JDE?